# How to wait for multiple nested promises to resolve?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise, axios

I am attempting to make several http requests (using axios), one to each url in a list. As soon as an individual request resolves, I want to make another request to a url constructed from the previous request's response. Finally, when all secondary requests are resolved, I want to do something with all of their responses.

I have attempted to accomplish this as follows:

```
let promises = [];

urls.forEach(url => {
  const promise = axios.get(url);

  promise.then(response => {
    promises.push(axios.get(response.data.url))
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
  // do something with responses
})
```

I expect the responses of all secondary url requests to be resolved when `.then(responses => {})` triggers, yet when this code triggers the responses array is empty.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: You probably want to consider using `async` / `await` here.

Answer (score 2):

Return the nested `axios.get` to a mapping callback, so that `Promise.all` will wait for all nested requests to complete first.

```
Promise.all(
  urls.map(
    url => axios.get(url).then(
      response => axios.get(response.data.url)
    )
  )
)
  .then((results) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is logical considering that very first `promise.then()` statement is asynchronous. The `urls.forEach` althoughy seemingly asynchronous, it is synchronous. Thus the `Promise.all()` is called before any promises are pushed to your array.

You could set it up like so:

```js
let promises = [];

urls.forEach(url => {
  promises.push(axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    return axios.get(response.data.url);
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
  // do something with responses
});
```

This chains the `.then()` directly onto the first axios request, which is then pushed onto the promises array.

Comment: It would be nicer to use `.map()` in place of `.forEach()` - then it would automatically create the array of promises.